# How to sort in a different way

Tags: mysql, sql

There are countries in MySQL table:

```
id | title
1  | USA  
2  | Spain
3  | Italy
4  | Canada
```

I need to select Italy on the top of list and other countries sorted by title below.
But 'order by' doesn't work.

```
(SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id = 3) UNION (SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id != 3 ORDER BY title)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First sort your data based on whether it is Italy or not, getting Italy first. Then sort based on the title.

```
SELECT * FROM countries
ORDER BY title='Italy' DESC, title
```

(The only trick you have to know -- or experiment with -- is that `FALSE` comes before `TRUE`, and hence the `DESC` in the code. I guess that makes sense if you convert them to 0 < 1.)

Comment: +1.  This also works in sqlite.  The `asc/desc` on the first sort is strange, but makes sense if you play with it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
  SELECT * FROM countries 

  ORDER BY  case when id !=3  then `title` end asc ,
            case when id =3   then `title` end asc ;
```

Comment: Why would this not list Canada before Italy?

Comment: I see you edited but I still suggest to first run your code to check and then post it. Still not ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id = 3
union
SELECT c.* FROM (SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id != 3 order by title) c
```